# creating new line in a row of table in latex

Tags: tables, line-breaking

[image]

Above is the table generated by my code. While I need table like one in the 2nd image given below. I searched a lot but couldn't find any solution. Can someone help?
My code is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\geometry{legalpaper, landscape, margin=0.2in}
\begin{document}
    %\begin{adjustwidth}{-8cm}{}
    %\begin{landscape}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{1mm}
    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Event}&\textbf{Destination state}&\textbf{Trans. rate}&\textbf{Condition}\\\hline
1. $PU$ AR. A vacant channel exists in the NCRN.&$(i_{n}+1,j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)$&$\lambda_P$&At least one vacant channel exists in the NCRN;$B_n(x)< M-R(x)$\\\hline 
    2. $PU$ AR. No vacant channel exists in the NCRN.$SU_{2N}$  terminates&$(i_{n}+1,j_{n1},j_{n2}-1,i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)$&$\lambda_P$&$B_n(x)=M– R(x); j_{n2} > 0$\\\hline
                3. $PU$ AR. No vacant channel exists in the NCRN.$SU_{1N}$ performs HO to the RCRN.&$(i_{n}+1,j_{n1}-1,j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1}+1,j_{r2},f)$&$\lambda_P$&$B_n(x) = M – R(x); j_{n2}=0; j_{n1} > 0: B_r(x) < R(x)$\\\hline
            4. $PU$ AR. An $SU_{1N}$ terminates.&$(i_{n}+1,j_{n1}-1,j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)$&$\lambda_P$&$B_n(x) = M – R(x); j_{n2}=j_{r2}=0; j_{n1} > 0; B(x)=M$\\\hline
        5. $SU_{1N}$ AR. A vacant channel exists in the NCRN.&$(i_{n},j_{n1}+1,j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)$&$\lambda_S$&$B_n(x) < M – R(x); B(x) < M$\\\hline
    6. $SU_{1N}$ AR. No vacant channel exists in the NCRN. $SU_{2N}$ terminates.&$(i_{n},j_{n1}+1,j_{n2}-1,i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)$&$\lambda_S$&$B_n(x)=M – R(x); j_{n2} > 0$\\\hline
 7. $SU_{2N}$ AR. A vacant channel exists in NCRN&$(i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2}+1,i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)$&$\lambda_S$&$B_n(x) < M – R(x)$\\\hline
    8. $SU_{2N}$ AR. No vacant channel exists in NCRN. Vacant channel exists in RCRN.&$(i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2}+1,f)$&$\lambda_S$&$B_n(x)=M – R(x); B_r(x) < R(x)$\\\hline
        9. $PU$ DP from the NCRN.&$(i_{n}-1,j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)$&$i_n\;\mu_P$&There is at least one $PU$ service in the NCRN; $i_n>0$.\\\hline
            10. $PU$ DP from the RCRN.&$(i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r}-1,j_{r1},j_{r2},f)$&$i_r\;\mu_P$&$Ir > 0$\\\hline
                11. $SU_{1N}$ DP from the NCRN.&$(i_{n},j_{n1}-1,j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)$&$J_{n1}\;\mu_S$&$j_{n1} > 0$\\\hline
            12. $SU_{1N}$ DP from the RCRN. &$(i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1}-1,j_{r2},f)$&$j_{r1}\;\mu_S$&$Jr > 0$\\\hline
         13. $SU_{2N}$ DP from the NCRN.&$(i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2}-1,i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)$&$ j_{n2}\;\mu_S$&$ j_{n2} > 0$\\\hline
     14. $SU_{2N}$ DP from the RCRN.&$(i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2}-1,f)$&$j_{r1}\;\mu_S$&$j_{r1} > 0$\\\hline
15. Idle channel failure.&$(i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f+1)$&$(M-B(x))\;\lambda_F$&There is at least one idle channel in the CRN; $B(x) < M$\\\hline
    16. An occupied channel fails. An idle channel exists in the CRN.&$(in,j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f+1)$&$(B(x)-f)\;\lambda_F$&$F<B(x)<M$ \\\hline
        17. An occupied channel fails. No idle channels exist in the CRN. An $SU_{1N}$ terminates.  &$(i_{n}+1,j_{n1}-1,j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f+1)$&$(M-f)\;\lambda_F$&$B(x) = M; j_{n1}>0;j_{n2}=j_{r2}=0$\\\hline
            18. An occupied channel fails. No idle channels exist in the CRN. An $SU_{2N}$ terminates.&$    (i_{n}+1,j_{n1},j_{n2}-1,i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f+1)$&$(M-f)\;\lambda_F$&$B(x)=M; j_{n2} > 0$\\\hline
                 19. An occupied channel fails. No idle channels exist in the CRN. A $PU_{N}$ terminates&$  (i_{n}-1,j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f+1)$&$
                 (M-f)\;\lambda_F$&$B(x) = M; j_{n1}= j_{n2}=j_{r2}=0; i_{n}>0;$ \\\hline
            20. An occupied channel fails. No idle channels exist in the CRN. An $SU_{1R}$ terminates&$ (i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1}-1,j_{r2},f+1)$&$(M-f)\;\lambda_F$&$B(x)=M; B_n(x) = 0; j_{r2}=0; j_{r1}>0; j_{n1}=0;$\\\hline
        21. An occupied channel fails. No idle channels exist in the CRN. An $SU_{2R}$ terminates&$ (i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2}-1,f+1)$&$(M-f)\;\lambda_F$&$B(x)=M; B_n(x)=M-R(x); j_{r2} > 0.$ \\\hline
    22. An occupied channel fails. No idle channels exist in the CRN. A $PU_R$ terminates&$ (i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r}-1,j_{r1},j_{r2},f+1)$&$(M-f)\;\lambda_F$&$B(x) = M; B_n(x)=j_{r1}=j_{r2}=j_{n2}=0; i_{r}>0$\\\hline
23. A failed channel is repaired&$  (i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f-1)$&$F\;\mu_R$&$f>0$\\\hline                 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just change `\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}` to `\begin{tabular}{llll}` (remove every `|`)... Then add an `\hline` just before and after the title and romove all others except last one... You can use also `\toprule` `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` by using `booktabs` package.

Comment: For the booktabs package see here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables at section 11.3

Comment: In order to get automatic linebreaks in table cells, you could use `p{5cm}` (or any othe length of your choice)  instead of `l` for the first  and last column.

Comment: Just use `\newline` …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe you liked:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{legalpaper, landscape, margin=0.2in}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcounter{tabrow}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\stepcounter{tabrow}\textbf{\thetabrow}}r}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
%    \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{1mm}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{N 
                             L 
                    *{2}{>{$}l<{$}}
                         >{$}L<{$}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Event}}
    &   \textbf{Destination state} 
        &   \textbf{Trans. rate} 
            &   \textbf{Condition}                              \\
\midrule
&   $PU$ AR. A vacant channel exists in the NCRN.
    &   (i_{n}+1,j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)
        &   \lambda_P   &   \text{At least one vacant channel exists in the NCRN; } B_n(x)< M-R(x)                                                \\
&   $PU$ AR. No vacant channel exists in the NCRN. $SU_{2N}$ terminates
    &   (i_{n}+1,j_{n1},j_{n2}-1,i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)
        &   \lambda_P   &   B_n(x)=M– R(x); j_{n2} > 0          \\
&   $PU$ AR. No vacant channel exists in the NCRN. $SU_{1N}$ performs HO to the RCRN.
    &   (i_{n}+1,j_{n1}-1,j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1}+1,j_{r2},f)
        &   \lambda_P   &   B_n(x) = M – R(x); j_{n2}=0; j_{n1} > 0: B_r(x) < R(x)   \\
&   $PU$ AR. An $SU_{1N}$ terminates.
    &   (i_{n}+1,j_{n1}-1,j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)
        &   \lambda_P   &   B_n(x) = M – R(x); j_{n2}=j_{r2}=0; j_{n1} > 0; B(x)=M    \\ 
&   $SU_{1N}$ AR. A vacant channel exists in the NCRN.
    &   (i_{n},j_{n1}+1,j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)   
        &   \lambda_S   &   B_n(x) < M – R(x); B(x) < M         \\
&   $SU_{1N}$ AR. No vacant channel exists in the NCRN. $SU_{2N}$ terminates.
    &   (i_{n},j_{n1}+1,j_{n2}-1,i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)
        &   \lambda_S   &   B_n(x)=M – R(x); j_{n2} > 0         \\
&   $SU_{2N}$ AR. A vacant channel exists in NCRN
    &   (i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2}+1,i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)   
        &   \lambda_S   &   B_n(x) < M – R(x)                   \\
&   $SU_{2N}$ AR. No vacant channel exists in NCRN. Vacant channel exists in RCRN.
    &   (i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2}+1,f)
        &   \lambda_S   &   B_n(x)=M – R(x); B_r(x) < R(x)    \\
&   $PU$ DP from the NCRN.
    &   (i_{n}-1,j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)
        &   i_n\;\mu_P  &   \text{There is at least one $PU$ service in the NCRN; } i_n>0. \\
&   $PU$ DP from the RCRN.
    &   (i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r}-1,j_{r1},j_{r2},f)
        &   i_r\;\mu_P &    Ir > 0              \\
&   $SU_{1N}$ DP from the NCRN.
    &   (i_{n},j_{n1}-1,j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)
        &   J_{n1}\;\mu_S   &   j_{n1} > 0      \\
&   $SU_{1N}$ DP from the RCRN.
    &   (i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1}-1,j_{r2},f)
        &   j_{r1}\;\mu_S   &   Jr > 0          \\
&   $SU_{2N}$ DP from the NCRN.
    &   (i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2}-1,i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)
        &   j_{n2}\;\mu_S   &   j_{n2} > 0     \\
&   $SU_{2N}$ DP from the RCRN.
    &   (i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2}-1,f)
        &   j_{r1}\;\mu_S   &   j_{r1} > 0    \\
&   Idle channel failure.
    &   (i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f+1)
        &   (M-B(x))\;\lambda_F &   \text{There is at least one idle channel in the CRN; } B(x)<M     \\
&   An occupied channel fails. An idle channel exists in the CRN.
    &   (in,j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f+1)
        &   (B(x)-f)\;\lambda_F &   F<B(x)<M  \\
&   An occupied channel fails. No idle channels exist in the CRN. An $SU_{1N}$ terminates. 
    &   (i_{n}+1,j_{n1}-1,j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f+1)
        &   (M-f)\;\lambda_F    &   B(x) = M; j_{n1}>0;j_{n2}=j_{r2}=0\\
&   An occupied channel fails. No idle channels exist in the CRN. An $SU_{2N}$ terminates.
    &   (i_{n}+1,j_{n1},j_{n2}-1,i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f+1)
        &   (M-f)\;\lambda_F    &   B(x)=M; j_{n2} > 0    \\
&   An occupied channel fails. No idle channels exist in the CRN. A $PU_{N}$ terminates
    &   (i_{n}-1,j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f+1)
        &   (M-f)\;\lambda_F    &   B(x) = M; j_{n1}= j_{n2}=j_{r2}=0; i_{n}>0; \\
&   An occupied channel fails. No idle channels exist in the CRN. An $SU_{1R}$ terminates
    &   (i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1}-1,j_{r2},f+1) 
        &   (M-f)\;\lambda_F    &   B(x)=M; B_n(x) = 0; j_{r2}=0; j_{r1}>0; j_{n1}=0;\\
&   An occupied channel fails. No idle channels exist in the CRN. An $SU_{2R}$ terminates
    &   (i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2}-1,f+1)
        &   (M-f)\;\lambda_F    &   B(x)=M; B_n(x)=M-R(x); j_{r2} > 0. \\
&   An occupied channel fails. No idle channels exist in the CRN. A $PU_R$ terminates
    &   (i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r}-1,j_{r1},j_{r2},f+1) 
        &   (M-f)\;\lambda_F    &   B(x)=M; B_n(x)=j_{r1}=j_{r2}=j_{n2}=0; i_{r}>0\\
&   A failed channel is repaired
    &   (i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f-1)   
        &   F\;\mu_R   &   f>0          \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

used is `tabularx`, rows are numbered automatically, ...

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked and solved my problem to the best.

Comment: @Abdullah1, apparently not .you accept other answer (as the best) :-)

Comment: I didn't know ticking one unticks another. I just came across this. Lolz.... However, I think that all effort-makers are worth praising.

Answer (score 2):

Not much to change, I added two packages (booktabs and array), removed all the \hline commands and changed the definition of your tabular, as you can see:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}%% <= new
\usepackage{array}%% <= new
\geometry{legalpaper, landscape, margin=0.2in}
\begin{document}
    %\begin{adjustwidth}{-8cm}{}
    %\begin{landscape}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{1mm}
    \begin{table}
      \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}lb{.35\linewidth}@{\hspace{2em}}l@{\hspace{2em}}l@{\hspace{2em}}p{.3\linewidth}}\toprule                
        \textbf{Event}&\textbf{Destination state}&\textbf{Trans. rate}&\textbf{Condition}\\\midrule
1.& $PU$ AR. A vacant channel exists in the NCRN.&$(i_{n}+1,j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)$&$\lambda_P$&At least one vacant channel exists in the NCRN;$B_n(x)< M-R(x)$\\ 
2.& $PU$ AR. No vacant channel exists in the NCRN.$SU_{2N}$  terminates&$(i_{n}+1,j_{n1},j_{n2}-1,i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)$&$\lambda_P$&$B_n(x)=M– R(x); j_{n2} > 0$\\
3.& $PU$ AR. No vacant channel exists in the NCRN.$SU_{1N}$ performs HO to the RCRN.&$(i_{n}+1,j_{n1}-1,j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1}+1,j_{r2},f)$&$\lambda_P$&$B_n(x) = M – R(x); j_{n2}=0; j_{n1} > 0: B_r(x) < R(x)$\\
4.& $PU$ AR. An $SU_{1N}$ terminates.&$(i_{n}+1,j_{n1}-1,j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)$&$\lambda_P$&$B_n(x) = M – R(x); j_{n2}=j_{r2}=0; j_{n1} > 0; B(x)=M$\\
5.&$SU_{1N}$ AR. A vacant channel exists in the NCRN.&$(i_{n},j_{n1}+1,j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)$&$\lambda_S$&$B_n(x) < M – R(x); B(x) < M$\\
6.& $SU_{1N}$ AR. No vacant channel exists in the NCRN. $SU_{2N}$ terminates.&$(i_{n},j_{n1}+1,j_{n2}-1,i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)$&$\lambda_S$&$B_n(x)=M – R(x); j_{n2} > 0$\\
7.& $SU_{2N}$ AR. A vacant channel exists in NCRN&$(i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2}+1,i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)$&$\lambda_S$&$B_n(x) < M – R(x)$\\
8.& $SU_{2N}$ AR. No vacant channel exists in NCRN. Vacant channel exists in RCRN.&$(i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2}+1,f)$&$\lambda_S$&$B_n(x)=M – R(x); B_r(x) < R(x)$\\
9.& $PU$ DP from the NCRN.&$(i_{n}-1,j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)$&$i_n\;\mu_P$&There is at least one $PU$ service in the NCRN; $i_n>0$.\\
10.& $PU$ DP from the RCRN.&$(i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r}-1,j_{r1},j_{r2},f)$&$i_r\;\mu_P$&$Ir > 0$\\
11.& $SU_{1N}$ DP from the NCRN.&$(i_{n},j_{n1}-1,j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)$&$J_{n1}\;\mu_S$&$j_{n1} > 0$\\
12.& $SU_{1N}$ DP from the RCRN. &$(i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1}-1,j_{r2},f)$&$j_{r1}\;\mu_S$&$Jr > 0$\\
13.& $SU_{2N}$ DP from the NCRN.&$(i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2}-1,i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f)$&$ j_{n2}\;\mu_S$&$ j_{n2} > 0$\\
14.& $SU_{2N}$ DP from the RCRN.&$(i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2}-1,f)$&$j_{r1}\;\mu_S$&$j_{r1} > 0$\\
15.& Idle channel failure.&$(i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f+1)$&$(M-B(x))\;\lambda_F$&There is at least one idle channel in the CRN; $B(x) < M$\\
16.& An occupied channel fails. An idle channel exists in the CRN.&$(in,j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f+1)$&$(B(x)-f)\;\lambda_F$&$F<B(x)<M$ \\
17.& An occupied channel fails. No idle channels exist in the CRN. An $SU_{1N}$ terminates.  &$(i_{n}+1,j_{n1}-1,j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f+1)$&$(M-f)\;\lambda_F$&$B(x) = M; j_{n1}>0;j_{n2}=j_{r2}=0$\\
18.& An occupied channel fails. No idle channels exist in the CRN. An $SU_{2N}$ terminates.&$    (i_{n}+1,j_{n1},j_{n2}-1,i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f+1)$&$(M-f)\;\lambda_F$&$B(x)=M; j_{n2} > 0$\\
19.& An occupied channel fails. No idle channels exist in the CRN. A $PU_{N}$ terminates&$  (i_{n}-1,j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f+1)$&$
                 (M-f)\;\lambda_F$&$B(x) = M; j_{n1}= j_{n2}=j_{r2}=0; i_{n}>0;$ \\
20.& An occupied channel fails. No idle channels exist in the CRN. An $SU_{1R}$ terminates&$ (i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1}-1,j_{r2},f+1)$&$(M-f)\;\lambda_F$&$B(x)=M; B_n(x) = 0; j_{r2}=0; j_{r1}>0; j_{n1}=0;$\\
21.& An occupied channel fails. No idle channels exist in the CRN. An $SU_{2R}$ terminates&$ (i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2}-1,f+1)$&$(M-f)\;\lambda_F$&$B(x)=M; B_n(x)=M-R(x); j_{r2} > 0.$ \\
22.& An occupied channel fails. No idle channels exist in the CRN. A $PU_R$ terminates&$ (i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r}-1,j_{r1},j_{r2},f+1)$&$(M-f)\;\lambda_F$&$B(x) = M; B_n(x)=j_{r1}=j_{r2}=j_{n2}=0; i_{r}>0$\\
23.& A failed channel is repaired&$  (i_{n},j_{n1},j_{n2},i_{r},j_{r1},j_{r2},f-1)$&$F\;\mu_R$&$f>0$\\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\end{document}
```

Ok, it would not fit in one page, if I hadn't reduced the font size to 10 pt. Reason is that you have some rows more than in your example pic.

And to get bold numbering, you'd have to make every single number bold. Better to have a bold printed column, so I added a first column with the numbers in `\bfseries`.

Looks like this:

[image: complicated tabular]

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, the titles above don't conform to the lines below them and creates confusion. Overall, the help is appreciable.